# Rails: How to make a form remote?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, forms, ruby-on-rails-4, syntax

I'm trying to make my comment form remote, but no matter how I add `remote: true`, I get an error.

I want to add `remote: true` to this line:

```
<%= form_for [@thing, @comment] do |f| %>
```

What is the proper syntax to achieve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
<%= form_for([@thing, @comment], remote: true) do |f| %>
```